# How to Convert Google PRIVATE_KEY to Base64 Encoded Signature

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift4.2, swift5

How I convert google `Private_key` to `Base64 Encoded Signature`.
I have done the same implementation in objective-c, but I couldn't find the same implementation in swift.
please, anyone help me ... Thanks in advance

```
NSString *key = keys.gOOGLE_PRIVATE_KEY;
NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/maps/api/directions/json?%@&sensor=false&client=%@", query, keys.gOOGLE_CLIENT_ID];

// Stores the url in a NSData.
NSData *urlData = [url dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

// URL-safe Base64 coder/decoder.
GTMStringEncoding *encoding = [GTMStringEncoding rfc4648Base64WebsafeStringEncoding];

// Decodes the URL-safe Base64 key to binary.
NSData *binaryKey = [encoding decode:key];

// Signs the URL.
unsigned char result[CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH];
CCHmac(kCCHmacAlgSHA1,
               [binaryKey bytes], [binaryKey length],
               [urlData bytes], [urlData length],
               &result);
NSData *binarySignature = [NSData dataWithBytes:&result length:CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH];

// Encodes the signature to URL-safe Base64.
NSString *signature = [encoding encode:binarySignature];
```

Comment: If you have working code in objective-c and I don't know how to translate it to the swift, why you don't stay in objective-c implementation and use it in swift code? You can easily use objective-c code in swift

Comment: Yes, but for this I need to create another class, that's way I'm looking this implementation in swift.